# Prolog; find list item

Tags: list, prolog

I have a list of pairs and want to find the element with the corresponding first value.

```
?- findconn1(9, [(9,[23,33]),(42,[21,322])], R).
```

So in this case I want the result to be `(9,[23,23])` in `R`.

The code is

```
findconn(X, [], R).
findconn(X, [(H,T)|Y], R) :-
   member(X, H),
   findConn(X, Y),
   append(T, T, R).
```

It always returns `false` despite that the element is present. And also is there any other way to return as I'm quite new to Prolog.

Comment: YOu don't need to use `member/2`, use pattern matching.

Comment: How would I do that

Comment: I added the code below, pattern matching is all what you need.

Comment: `member(X,H)` is, for example, asking `member(9, 9)` which would of course fail since your second argument isn't even a list.

Comment: @Coder. Why did you delete your answer? It is clearly superior to the other answer, which is basically a specialized boilerplate reimplementation of `member/2`...

Comment: @repeat, I thought because the op liked more the first implementation I thought may it was not so helpful... anyway brought it back :) !! (I agree to the part `boilerplate reimplementation of member/2` that's why I choose simply to use `member/2`...).

Comment: @coder. Good! Next time, don't delete. Let SO work. Let the votes/comments/edits speak...

Comment: @repeat, Ok thanks, for the comment!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't need `member/2`. Just use pattern matching with a base case and a recursion case like this:

```
findconn1(N,[(N,B)|_],N-B). %basecase

findconn1(N,[(_,_)|T],R):-
    findconn1(N,T,R).
```

So when you type a query:

```
?- findconn1(42,[(9,[23,33]),(42,[21,322])],R).
    R = 42-[21, 322]
```

You get result in R.

Comment: If I had to do the same in standard ml, then how would I do it.

Comment: What do you mean by standard ml?

Comment: Like if I want to implement the same functionality in standard ml programming language

Comment: If you mean imperative programming language like java etc, then you need to use loops and you can't use this recursive structure because java has nothing like pattern matching as Prolog has. Every language differs from other in some way. These are called declarative language and prolog is logical language so for java for example you need loops etc

Comment: Don't try to compare Prolog with other languages because that 's the wrong way to go and this language is totally different from python or java.

Comment: Using `member/2` is definitely the way to go here! Instead, you chose to basically reimplement it. Boilerplate code? Bad!

Comment: @repeat thanks for your comment but everyone has his own way of writing code. Personally i'm no big fan of built-ins nor any beginner will learn anything in that way. Well, it was `Bad` if it had bad complexity than member predicate.

Comment: @repeat No need to yell, we can definitely understand you without those exclamation marks.

Comment: @RoadRunner. What are you talking about? Could you please quote the text I wrote that offended you? I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple way using built-in `member/2` predicate:

```
findconn1(X,L,(X,L1)):- member((X,L1),L).
```

Example:

```
?- findconn1(9,[(9,[23,33]),(42,[21,322])],R).
R =  (9, [23, 33]) ;
false.
```

With the above solution note that if 9 exists more than once you get all solutions:

```
?- findconn1(9,[(9,[23,33]),(42,[21,322]),(9,[1,2])],R).
R =  (9, [23, 33]) ;
R =  (9, [1, 2]).
```